# Redirect to another page in javascript after promise fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, promise

I have a form which is submitting through javascript. on form submits I call following function to run ajax request in loop to update all versions, I want to redirect to another url when all versions are updated. I am trying to use promise resolve method but not sure how can it be used with ajax and ajax in loop, following is my code.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#frm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var fields = $(this).serialize();
            var a =  $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: fields,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                    count += updateVersion(fields,a);
                },
                error: function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                }
            });
            console.log('count',count);
        })
    });
    </script>
```

After success I am calling a method "updateVersion" in which I have used ajax to update json for multiple versions.

```
function updateVersion(fields,e){
    var versions = ["v5","v6","v7","v8","v9","v4"];
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        $.each(versions, function(key, v) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: e.serialize()+ "&update_json=1&version="+v,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                    status = 1;
                },
                error: function(res) {
                    console.log(res)
                }
            });
        });
        resolve(window.location.href= "https://www.example.com");
    });
    promise.then((successMessage) => {
      console.log('Got data! Promise fulfilled.');
    }, error => {
      console.log('Promise rejected.');
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous, which means you're calling `resolve()` immediately, not after the requests have finished. Use `Promise.all()` instead.

Comment: Here's how: https://pastebin.com/n04ysEsN

Comment: I'm thinking why the url field is empty. Because Internal server error is server side and and empty string is probably causing it to hit localhost or wherever it is deployed.

Comment: @Sreeram its not the problem with url because values are updating for some versions but not for all. And by default it redirects to self url

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the help. By trying your code i am able to show the error message but my problem not get solved yet, still my json are not updating for all versions